# SQL query works in mySQL, breaks in Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a SQL SELECT query that works in mySQL, both from PHPmyadmin and from the console. However, when it was converted to Laravel query builder, it borked with the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not
in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wcce_dev.client_contacts.family_name'
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The following is the SQL SELECT query:

```
SELECT `clients`.name, `clients`.address_1, `client_contacts`.family_name,
  `client_contacts`.given_name, `client_contacts`.office_country,
  `client_contacts`.office_city, `client_contacts`.office_number, `client_contacts`.position, `contact_titles`.description
FROM `clients`
INNER JOIN `client_contacts`
ON `clients`.entry = `client_contacts`.client
INNER JOIN `contact_titles`
ON `client_contacts`.title = `contact_titles`.code
GROUP BY `clients`.entry
ORDER BY `clients`.entry ASC;
```

The following is the Laravel query builder statement:

```
DB::table('clients')
->select('clients.name', 'clients.address_1', 'client_contacts.family_name',
  'client_contacts.given_name', 'client_contacts.office_country', 
  'client_contacts.office_city', 'client_contacts.office_number', 
  'client_contacts.position', 'contact_titles.description')
->join('client_contacts','clients.entry','=','client_contacts.client')
->join('contact_titles','client_contacts.title','=','contact_titles.code')
->groupBy('clients.entry')
->orderBy('clients.entry','asc')
->get();
```

It's very strange. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `clients.entry` field to your select query. and try

Comment: Same error? Then try `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` or direct change it from MySql settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your related table `client_contacts` can have more than one row which corresponds to a row in the `clients` table. Even if it won't happen in reality, the db doesn't know that and throws an error.

You have two options

1. Turn off `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` so that it can pick one row at random and display that
2. Precede each aggregate column with `MAX()` so that it just gets one of them.

The resulting query would look like this:

```
SELECT `clients`.name, `clients`.address_1, 
  MAX(`client_contacts`.family_name),
  MAX(`client_contacts`.given_name), 
  MAX(`client_contacts`.office_country),
  MAX(`client_contacts`.office_city), 
  MAX(`client_contacts`.office_number),   
  MAX(`client_contacts`.position), 
  MAX(`contact_titles`.description)
FROM `clients`
INNER JOIN `client_contacts`
ON `clients`.entry = `client_contacts`.client
INNER JOIN `contact_titles`
ON `client_contacts`.title = `contact_titles`.code
GROUP BY `clients`.entry
ORDER BY `clients`.entry ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in mysql, phpmyadmin then try

SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));

And if you using group by then group by column must be present in select query
"'clients.entry'"

```
DB::table('clients')
->select('clients.name', 'clients.address_1', 'client_contacts.family_name',
  'client_contacts.given_name', 'client_contacts.office_country', 
  'client_contacts.office_city', 'client_contacts.office_number', 
  'client_contacts.position', 'contact_titles.description', 'clients.entry')
->join('client_contacts','clients.entry','=','client_contacts.client')
->join('contact_titles','client_contacts.title','=','contact_titles.code')
->groupBy('clients.entry')
->orderBy('clients.entry','asc')
->get();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( What really annoys me is why it works in mySQL 8 directly, but not through Laravel 10.